# Backoff seem to be ignored in a Spring JmsListener

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am writing a Spring JmsListener to an MQ series. I have some problems when I am implementing the backoff strategy. It's seem to be ignored. Below is my JMS config:

```java
@Configuration
public class Jmsconfig implements JmsListenerConfigurer {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Jmsconfig.class);
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Value("${mqueue.error}")
    String mqError;

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

            // Définir sessionTransacted sur false
            FixedBackOff fbo = new FixedBackOff(); // or ExponentialBackOff
            fbo.setMaxAttempts(3);
            fbo.setInterval(5000);

            //factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
            //factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            factory.setRecoveryInterval(3000L);
            factory.setBackOff(fbo);

            return factory;
    }

    //cache pour pouvoir recevoir les message asynchrones
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory handlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();

        factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return factory;
    }


    //désérialisation et mapping vers objet java
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(handlerMethodFactory());

    }    
}
```

I tried to activate SESSION TRANSACTED, and I had an infinite loop! When I display the attribute "JMSXDeliveryCount" it seems to be normal. It is incremented at each attempt but the maxattemps and interval is not respected!

Comment: Have a look at [Handling poison messages in IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=applications-handling-poison-messages-in-mq-classes-jms). Looks like the IBM MQ queue attributes BOTHRESH (backout threshold) and BOQNAME (backout requeue queue) are not defined for your queue by the administrator.

Comment: We can't do without those attributes ?

Comment: Because the Spring `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` does simply a reconnect with these settings, but it does not contain the logic to put poison messages on a back out queue. This logic is part of the IBM MQ JMS library and is based on the attributes BOTHRESH and BOQNAME.

Comment: I defined the bothresh and boqame , now it's work but i want to put a delay before each redelivery  message , i dont want to do it with thread.sleep , how i can do it ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do this with the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory`. In IBM MQ, you could use the queue manager's dead letter queue instead of an individual back out queue and then define a specific dead letter queue handler to replay the message with a delay, see [DLQ control data](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=table-dlq-control-data).